# Reading specific value with Openrowset in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

The aim here is to read a specific value from a different server and store the return value in a local parameter for use later.

Here is the error code:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Alarm'.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
declare @sql_string nvarchar(400);
declare @inhostnamn nvarchar(100) = 'BLUE65\SQLEXPRESS'
declare @inuser nvarchar(50) = 'dev1'
declare @password1 nvarchar(50) = 'dev1'
declare @database nvarchar(100) = 'Test_destroy'
declare @count_posts varchar(10)
declare @tabellnamn varchar(50) = 'Alarms'
declare @last_read_alarm varchar(30)

set  @tabellnamn = 'Logg'

set @sql_string = N'set @last_read_alarm1 = cast(last_read as nvarchar(30)) select * from openrowset (''SQLNCLI'', ''Server='+@inhostnamn+';UID='+@inuser+';Pwd='+@password1+';Database='+@database+';Persist Security Info=True'',''select Last_ID FROM '+@database +'.dbo.Logg where Tables_sql=''Alarm'' '')';

print 'string =' + @sql_string;

exec sp_executesql @sql_string, N'@last_read_alarm1 varchar(30) OUTPUT', @last_read_alarm1=@last_read_alarm OUTPUT;

select @last_read_alarm
print @last_read_alarm;
```

Now I am stuck. I cannot see the error I have made, and am hoping for a couple of different eyes.

Comment: Why not use a [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine)?

Comment: Yes I can use a linked server, but i'am learning SQL and don't understand the syntax error I have made, because In my eyes the syntax seems OK

Comment: Ok. Add two more quotation marks to the both sides of `Alarm`. It will look like this `''''Alarm''''`.

Comment: I will try it.
Did try Linked server just for testing also, and that part worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Andrei Odegov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3350428/andrei-odegov) for great assistance. It helped putting 4 `'` on each side.

The correct code would be in my case now:

```
set @sql_string = N'select @last_read_alarm= (select * from openrowset (''SQLNCLI'', ''Server='+@inhostnamn+';UID='+@inuser+';Pwd='+@password1+';Database='+@database+';Persist Security Info=True'',''select Last_ID FROM '+@database +'.dbo.Logg where Tables_sql='''''+@tmp_str+''''' ''))';
```

So the answer from the query will now end up in local variable `@last_read_alarm`.